# Error in MS Excel VBA macro script for number filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I've tried to write a script to apply a filter, I was trying to get the value from a cell and then apply greater than or equal to. But I guess I have some syntax.

```
Sub GTE()
'
' GTE Macro
'

'
    Dim var As Double
    var = Range("X1").Value
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
        ">=" + var, Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Comment: Use ampersand to concatenate values. This:  ">=" + var Should be ">=" & var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all the code you need. You don't need the line `Selection.Copy` to make the filter work.

```
Dim var As Double

var = Range("X1").Value
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    ">=" & var, Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: This worked like charm! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- Assign meaningful names to your procedures and variables
- No need to reference the `ActiveSheet` (*unless you really mean it*)
- You can refer to the table name by it's range name and then the listobject attached to it

---

When refering to ranges, try to fully qualify them.

Instead of this:

```
Range("X1").Value
```

Use this:

```
Thisworkbook.Worksheets("TheSheetName").Range("X1").Value
```

Or better this:

```
    ' Define and assign a worksheet variable
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TheSheetName")
    
    ' Define and assign the filter variable
    Dim filterValue As Double
    filterValue = targetSheet.Range("X1").Value
```

---

**Code:**

```
Public Sub FilterData()
    
    ' Define and assign a worksheet variable
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TheSheetName")
    
    ' Define and assign the filter variable
    Dim filterValue As Double
    filterValue = targetSheet.Range("X1").Value
    
    ' Define and assign the table (listobject)
    Dim dataTable As ListObject
    Set dataTable = Range("data").ListObject
    
    ' Filter the table. No need to reference the activesheet
    dataTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
                                        ">=" & filterValue, Operator:=xlAnd
                                        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You very much. Will remember these points:)